# Error while apt-get update not work

Tags: linux, kali-linux

```
apt-get update
Get:1 http://ftp.yzu.edu.tw/Linux/kali kali-rolling InRelease [30.5 kB]
Reading package lists... Done                      
E: Release file for http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 10h 37min 24s). Updates for this repository will not be applied
```

source list

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

Answer (score 6):

It says "E: Release file for http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 10h 37min 24s). Updates for this repository will not be applied"

So it sounds like your source is not valid yet (invalid for another 10h 37min 24s). Try again after then.

I thought you might have had the wrong source set, but https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories says it looks right. So instead your computer's date could be set wrong, try checking / setting the date & timezone. (`sudo ntpdate -v pool.ntp.org` might work)

Comment: can you suggest the right source.list

Comment: I googled kali's default sources, looks like it's right, but another option is the date's set wrong so try checking/setting the date & timezone (google knows how, there's a few different ways)

Comment: That's good! You're welcome. On these sites it's preferred to [accept the best answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking the check-mark next to it, instead of just saying thanks *(sometimes it's weird with recommending "no thanks")*.

Comment: This works for me. The system hour was wrong, and when I fix it, the command works well.

Answer (score 3):

sudo systemctl restart ntp.service && ntpq -p

OR

Manually:"sudo nano /etc/ntp.conf" AND add the following lines.

server 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org
server 1.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org
server 2.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org
server 3.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org

Answer (score 1):

```
E: Release file for http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 10h 37min 24s). Updates for this repository will not be applied
```

You will get this error when your system time isn't correct. Try to change the system time and do apt-get update.
For me, it worked flawlessly...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue trying:

```
sudo apt-get update
Get:1 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling InRelease [30.6 kB]
Reading package lists... Done        
E: Release file for http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 3h 0min 29s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
```

To fix this I ran:

```
sudo apt install ntp
```

then after that finished, I had to run

```
sudo systemctl start ntpsec
```

Then you can finally run:

```
sudo apt update
```

with no errors. Hope this helps.